# meaning of these formal parameters in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I read these two different types of declaration of multidimensional array in  formal parameters of a function in C.

`int c[][10];`

`int (*c)[10];`

How these two are same ? I am not getting the feel of it. Can anyone explain this with some example what the second one is trying to do?
Sorry if this has been previously asked..Please redirect me to the duplicate if any.

Answer (score 8):

As a function argument, `int* c` and `int c[]` or even `int c[7]` are identical. See [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html).

The `[10]` part only tells the compiler how to do the arithmetic for accessing an element in the array - e.g. `c[3][5]`. Both these declarations are for a multidimensional array whose second dimension (as far as the compiler is concerned, inside this function) is of size 10.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_all(int c[][2], int len) {
    int res = 0, i ,j;
    for (i=0; i < len; i++)
        for (j=0; j < 2; j++)
            res += c[i][j];
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int a[3][2] = { { 1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
    printf("sum is %d\n", sum_all(a, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the array is not checked to be of size 2, in this example. We could have passed a single dimensional array. The compiler does not care; we only told him how to access the elements in this array.

Answer (score 4):

N1570:

> **6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
> ...
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
>                *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
>                       array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
>                      array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
>                     actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many
>                      elements as specified by the size expression.

So, within the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are both equivalent to `T *a`; all three declare `a` as a pointer to `T`.  In this particular case, `T` is "10-element array of `int`".

This goes hand-in-hand with the following:

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>  unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
> type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points
>                to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
>               register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Suppose you have an array declared as

```
int arr[5][10];
```

When you pass the array expression `arr` to a function, such as

```
foo( arr );
```

the array expression `arr` is converted from type "5-element array of 10-element array of `int`" to type "pointer to 10-element array of `int`", and that pointer value is what gets passed to the function.  So your function prototype for `foo` would read as

```
void foo( int (*c)[10] )
```

or

```
 void foo( int c[][10] )
```

or even

```
 void foo( int c[5][10] )
```

but in all three cases, `c` is a pointer to an array, not a 2D array.

Comment: `In this particular case, T is "10-element array of int".` - are you sure?  I am not sure this is an accurate description.

Comment: @Elazar One could argue about the "description", but it is an accurate assessment of the situation.

Comment: @DanielFischer The question was whether or not `sizeof(*a) == 10*sizeof(int)`. The answer turns out to be "yes", and I did not know that.

Comment: +1 this is much better than my answer (but I don't want to remove it, assuming it is not really misleading in any way)

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens when you define `int c[5][10]` and then pass `c` to a routine. The array `c` will automatically be converted to a pointer to its first element, which is an array of 10 `int`.

So the language designers arranged it so that when you declare a parameter with `c[][10]`, it is automatically adjusted to match the conversion that will happen. The compiler changes a parameter of type array of array of `int` to a parameter of type pointer to array of `int`.